# Where in Padma Purana the following verse about parampara is located?

Tags: vaishnavism, identification-request, guru, padma-purana

> Sampradaya-vihina ye mantras te nisphala matah
>   Atah kalau bhavisyanti catvarah sampradayinah catvarah sampradayinah
>
> Sri-brahma-rudra-sanakah vaisnavah ksiti-pavanah
>   Catvaras te kalau bhavya hy utkale purusottamatAtah kalau bhavisyanti

**Meaning:**

> 'Any mantra that does not come in disciplic succession is considered
>   to be fruitless. Therefore, four divine individuals will appear in the
>   age of Kali to found disciplic schools. The founders of these four
>   Vaisnava sampradayas are Laksmi or Sri, Brahma, Rudra and Sanaka
>   Rishi, and the acaryas of the Kali Age who follow their lines will
>   appear in the holy city of Purusottama in Orissa.

This verse looks like a prediction of various Vaishnava Sampradayas which appeared in Kali age. Now where this verse is located in Padma Purana?

Comment: Some Gaudiya  vaishnava sites are also mentioning that this verse is from a text called Garga Samhita  10.16-22-26. But so far i haven't found the verse  in their Garga Samhita version available online. Also i doubt about presence of this verse in Padma Purana.

Comment: Why do you think it is in Padma Puraana? @NarayanaSharma ? Any article, or book, or website?

Comment: @AnuragSingh yes, prabhupada quoted this in his works which I want to know its authenticity. I got this from a Gaudiya website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verse is not extant in the manuscripts of the Padma Purana which are known today, but the verse was quoted in some of the books of the Hindu authors from the previous centuries.
Thus in the Prameya Ratnavali of Baladeva Vidyabhushana, a Gaudiya Vaishnava author and acarya, he quoted [that verse:](https://nitaaiveda.com/All_Scriptures_By_Acharyas/Baladeva_Vidyabhushana/Prameya_Ratnavali.htm)

> First Prameya,
>
> TEXT 5
>
> yad uktam padma-purane
>   sampradya-vihina ye
>        mantras te nishphala matah
>   atahh kalau bhavishyanti
>        catvarah sampradayinah
>
> shri-brahma-rudra-sanaka
>        vaishnavah kshiti-pavanah
>   catvaras te kalau bhavya
>        hy utkale purushottamat
>
> yat—which; uktam—is spoken; padma-purane—in the Padma Purana; sampradaya-vihinah—those who are not connected to the bona-fide disciplic succession; ye—those who; mantrah—mantras; te—they; nishphalah—without result; matah—are considered; atah—for this reason; kalau—in the age of Kali; bhavishyanti—there will be; catvarah—four; sampradayah—bona-fide disciplic successions; shri—from Lakshmi-devi; brahma—from Lord Brahma; rudra—from Lord Shiva; sanakah—and from Sanaka and the Kumara sons of Brahma; vaishnavah—in relation to Lord Vishnu; kshiti—the world; pavanah—purifying; catvarah—four; te—they; kalau—in the age of kali; bhavyah—will be; hi--indeed; utkale—in Orissa; purushottamat—from Jagannatha Puri.
>
> The Padma Purana explains: "Unless one is initiated by a bona-fide spiritual master in the disciplic succession, the mantra he might have received is without any effect. For this reason four Vaishnava disciplic successions, inaugurated by Lakshmi-devi, Lord Brahma, LordShiva, and the four Kumaras, will appear in the holy place of Jagannatha Puri, and purify the entire earth during the age of Kali."
>
> TEXT 6
>
> ramnujam shrih svi-cakre
>        madhvacriyam caturmukhah
>   shri-vishnu-svaminam rudro
>        nimbadityam catuhsanah
>
> ramanujam—Ramanuja; shrih—Lakshmi-devi; svi-cakre—selected; madvacaryam—Madhvacarya; caturmukah—Lord Brahma; shri-vishnu-svaminam—Vishnu Svami; rudrah—Lord Shiva; nimbadityam—Nimbarka; catuhsanah—the four Kumaras.
>
> Lakshmi-devi chose Ramanujacarya to represent her disciplic succession. In the same way Lord Brahma chose Madhvacarya, Lord Shiva chose Vishnu Svami, and the four Kumaras chose Nimbarka.

Comment: So, this is not there in any scriptures.

Comment: @NarayanaSharma Well, perhaps not in any manuscripts of the Padma Purana available in our modern age, but the verses were there in some old manuscripts.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa The first verse is from padma purana. The second verse seems like baladeva vidyabhusan's commentary on the first verse.

Comment: @RaRa Yes, it seems so.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa There is another hidden meaning of that verse which I read elsewhere, can't recollect where exactly now. The hidden meaning is that  all 4 sampradayas meet in Puri in the form of Gaudiya samprada. Gaudiya sampradaya has elements from all 4 sampradayas. Bhakt vinod Thakur says mahaprabhu took 2 principles each from 4 sampradayas.

Answer (score 0):

@ User 16618 The two principles accepted from each Sampradaya by Sri Caitanya Mahaprabhu

In the narration of Sri Navadvip-Dham-Mahatmya Srila Bhaktivinode Thakur relates the time when Sri Nityananda Prabhu took Srila Jiva Gosvami on a tour. Herein it is mentioned how Sri Chaitanya Mahaprabhu accepted two principles from each of the four sampradayas and incorporated these into His own sampradaya.

Ramanuja of the Sri-Sampradaya preached the philosophy of dasya-rasa and visishta-advaita. He was reborn as the gaura-bhakta named Ananta who lived near Vallabhacharya's house. Sri Chaitanya Mahaprabhu accepted the following two principles from the Laksmi-Sampradaya.

1.The concept of unalloyed devotion free from karma and jñana -ananya-bhakti.
2.Service to the devotees - bhakta-jana-seva.

Madhva of the Brahma-Sampradaya preached the dvaita philosophy. The following points were accepted from thissampradaya:

1.The complete defeat of the Mayavadi philosophy - Keval-advaita-nirasana.
2.The worship of the deity of Krishna and understanding it to be eternal - krsna-murti-sevana.

Vishnusvami of the Rudra-Sampradaya preached suddha-advaita philosophy. He was reborn as the Gaura-bhakta named Vallabha Bhatta who perfected his own sampradaya by Gauranga's mercy. Sri Chaitanya Mahaprabhu accepted the following from this sampradaya:

1.The sentiment of total dependence on Krishna - tadiya-sarvasva-bhava
2.The path of spontaneous devotional service - raga-marga.

Nimbarka of the Kumara-Sampradaya preached dvaita-advaita philosophy. He was reborn as the Gaura-bhakta named Keshava Kashmiri . Again, two points were accepted:

1.The need of taking exclusive shelter of Radhika - ekanta-radhikasraya.
2.The exalted mood of the gopis' love for Sri Krishna - gopi-bhava.
From Bhagavat Swami

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).