# Is Padma Purāṇa the source of this verse on Ṛṇānubandha (relationship due to one's past deeds)?

Tags: identification-request, sanskrit, shloka, padma-purana

The following verse has been used in a couple of answers [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aa%20Rupena%20Patni) and [this blog post](http://marriageastrologyandsynastry.blogspot.com/2018/05/introduction-of-rinanubandha-as-per.html) claims the verse is from the Padma Purāṇa although it doesn't mention the chapter # or the context.

> Definition [of [ṛṇānubandhana](http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?mode=3&script=ia&tran_input=RNAnubandhana&direct=se)] from the The Padma Purana
>
> > Runanubhanda Rupena Pashu Patni Suta Aalaya 
> >     Runakshaye Kshyayaanthi Tatra Parivedana
> >
> > Meaning: Every relationship is the result of previous birth bondage. Once the debt is annihilated, there is no relationship and hence the end of suffering in this Saṃsāra.

Is Padma Purāṇa really the source of this verse?

Comment: I've searched through Padmapurana but not found this Shloka.

Comment: @Pandya do you any location where you can search sanskrit verses using english transliterations?

Comment: @KrishnaVarna If you have Devanagari text, sanskritdocuments.org and sa.wikisoirce.org are good resources to search. Otherwise you have to search in pdfs available at Vedic reserve site.

Comment: @KrishnaVarna Try [GRETIL](http://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil.htm), [Digital Corpus of Sanskrit](http://www.sanskrit-linguistics.org/dcs/index.php) and [wisdomlib](http://wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book) - but not all Sanskrit texts, especially Puranas, have been transliterated yet.

Answer (score 1):

After searching through the Padma Purāṇa, it appears this verse isn't the part of the extant Padma Purāṇa.

This verse currently maybe traced to the Mahāsubhāṣitasaṃgraha (महासुभाषितसंग्रह).

> It's Sanskrit [quote number 7364](https://www.wisdomlib.org/sanskrit/quote/mss/subhashita-7364) in the said Mahāsubhāṣitasaṃgraha.

Although, we cannot be completely sure, considering several verses which are attributed to the Padma Purāṇa [are not extant in the manuscripts of the Padma Purana which are known today](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/27546/17833). Perhaps in the older /ancient text of Padma Purāṇa, such a verse did exist.

##### For now, the questioned verse belongs to the Mahāsubhāṣitasaṃgraha.